# i can't add classname when i click on a element by "addEventListener","click", "element.classList.add()"

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

My addEventListener is not working for each element with class='.plan-card' that I click on.

I expect that every time I click on an element with `class='plan-card'`, that element will be given the class `selected`, and the previously selected element with `class='selected'` will have that class removed.

My code:

```js
const steps = document.querySelectorAll(".stp");
const circleSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
const formInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".step-1 form input");
const plans = document.querySelectorAll(".plan-card");
const switcher = document.querySelector(".switch");
const addons = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
const total = document.querySelector(".total b")
const planPrice = document.querySelector(".plan-price");
let time;
let currentStep = 1;
let currentCircle = 0;
const obj = {
  plan: null,
  kind: null,
  price: null,
};

steps.forEach((step) => {
  const nextBtn = step.querySelector(".next-stp");
  const prevBtn = step.querySelector(".prev-stp");

  if (prevBtn) {
    prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.querySelector(`.step-${currentStep}`).style.display = "none";
      circleSteps[currentCircle].classList.remove("active");
      currentStep--;
      currentCircle--;
      document.querySelector(`.step-${currentStep}`).style.display = "flex";
      circleSteps[currentCircle].classList.add("active");
    })
  }


  nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(`.step-${currentStep}`).style.display = "none";
    circleSteps[currentCircle].classList.remove("active");
    if (currentStep < 5 && validateForm()) {
      currentStep++;
      currentCircle++;
    }
    document.querySelector(`.step-${currentStep}`).style.display = "flex";
    circleSteps[currentCircle].classList.add("active");
    summary(obj);
  })
})

function summary() {
  const planName = document.querySelector(".plan-name");
  const planPrice = document.querySelector(".plan-price");
  planPrice.innerHTML = `${obj.price.innerText}`;
  planName.innerHTML = `${obj.plan.innerText} (${obj.kind ? "yearly" : "monthly"})`;
}

function validateForm() {
  let valid = true;
  for (i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
    if (!formInputs[i].value) {
      valid = false;
      formInputs[i].classList.add("err");
      findLabel(formInputs[i]).nextElementSibling.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      valid = true;
      formInputs[i].classList.remove("err");
      findLabel(formInputs[i]).nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

function findLabel(el) {
  const idVal = el.id;
  const labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].htmlFor == idVal) return labels[i];
  }
}

plans.forEach((plan) => {
  plan.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".selected").classList.remove("selected")
    plan.classList.add("selected");
  });
})
```

```css
:root {
  --Marine-blue: hsl(213, 96%, 18%);
  --Purplish-blue: hsl(243, 100%, 62%);
  --Pastel-blue: hsl(228, 100%, 84%);
  --Light-blue: hsl(206, 94%, 87%);
  --Strawberry-red: hsl(354, 84%, 57%);
  --Cool-gray: hsl(231, 11%, 63%);
  --Light-gray: hsl(229, 24%, 87%);
  --Magnolia: hsl(217, 100%, 97%);
  --Alabaster: hsl(231, 100%, 99%);
  --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--Magnolia);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.form {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: var(--White);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px black;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.form-sidebar {
  background-image: url("./assets/images/bg-sidebar-desktop.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 568px;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .8rem;
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid var(--White);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--White);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.active .circle {
  background-color: var(--Light-blue) !important;
  color: var(--Marine-blue) !important;
}

.step-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .2rem;
}

.step-content span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--Light-gray);
  font-size: 13px;
}

.step-content b {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--White);
}

.stp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stp .header {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.header .title {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
}

.header .exp {
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
}

.next-stp {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: var(--Marine-blue);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-stp {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
}

.prev-stp:hover {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
}

.step-1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
}

.step-1 form {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.step-1 .label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form label {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.form .error {
  color: var(--Strawberry-red);
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: none;
}

.step-1 form .err {
  border: 2px solid var(--Strawberry-red);
}

.step-1 input {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--Cool-gray);
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
}

.step-1 input:focus {
  outline-color: var(--Purplish-blue);
}

.step-2 {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
}

.step-2 form {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

form .plan-card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid var(--Cool-gray);
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form .plan-card.selected {
  border: 2px solid var(--Purplish-blue);
  background-color: var(--Magnolia);
}

form .plan-card:hover {
  border: 2px solid var(--Purplish-blue);
}

.plan-card .plan-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .3rem;
}

.plan-info b {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
}

.plan-info span {
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.switcher {
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--Magnolia);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.switcher p {
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.switcher p.sw-active {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
}

.switcher .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 28px;
}

.switcher .switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--Marine-blue);
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

.switch input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.step-3 {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
}

.step-3 form {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.step-3 .box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--Cool-gray);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box input {
  accent-color: var(--Purplish-blue);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  user-select: none;
}

.ad-selected {
  border: 1px solid var(--Purplish-blue);
  background-color: var(--Magnolia);
}

.box .description {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.box .description label {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
  font-weight: 700;
  user-select: none;
}

.box .description small {
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.price {
  margin-left: auto;
  color: var(--Purplish-blue);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.step-4 {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
}

.step-4 .selection-box {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.step-4 .selection-container {
  background-color: var(--Magnolia);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.selected-plan,
.selected-addon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.plan-name,
.plan-price {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.service-name {
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.service-price {
  color: var(--Marine-blue);
  font-weight: 500;
}

.total {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: var(--Cool-gray);
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.total b {
  color: var(--Purplish-blue);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.step-5 {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    position: relative;
  }
  .form-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url(./assets/images/bg-sidebar-mobile.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 300px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .step-content {
    display: none;
  }
  .form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 375px;
  }
  .form-container {
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  .stp {
    width: 100%;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  .stp .header {
    padding-top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
  }
  .stp .header .title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
  .btns {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 80px;
    padding-inline: 1rem;
  }
  .next-stp,
  .prev-stp {
    margin: auto 0;
  }
  .step-1 .next-stp {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
  }
  .step-2 form {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  form .plan-card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  .switcher {
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/images/favicon-32x32.png">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hanken+Grotesk:wght@500;700;800&family=Inter:wght@400;700;800&family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Multi-step form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">

  <style>
    .attribution {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .attribution a {
      color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="form-container">
      <!-- Sidebar start -->
      <div class="form-sidebar">
        <div class="step active">
          <div class="circle active">1</div>
          <div class="step-content">
            <span>Step 1</span>
            <b>Your info</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
          <div class="circle">2</div>
          <div class="step-content">
            <span>Step 2</span>
            <b>Select your plan</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
          <div class="circle">3</div>
          <div class="step-content">
            <span>Step 3</span>
            <b>Add-ons</b>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
          <div class="circle">4</div>
          <div class="step-content">
            <span>Step 4</span>
            <b>Summary</b>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Sidebar end -->
      <!-- Step 1 start -->
      <div class="stp step-1">
        <div class="header">
          <h1 class="title">Personal info</h1>
          <p class="exp">Please provide your name, email address, and phone number.</p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="label">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <p class="error">This Field Is Required</p>
          </div>
          <input type="text" required id="name" placeholder="e.g. Stephen King">
          <div class="label">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <p class="error">This Field Is Required</p>
          </div>
          <input type="text" required id="email" placeholder="e.g. stephenking@lorem.com">
          <div class="label">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <p class="error">This Field Is Required</p>
          </div>
          <input type="text" required id="phone" placeholder="e.g. +1 234 567 890">
        </form>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="next-stp" type="submit">Next Step</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Step 1 end -->
      <!-- Step 2 start -->
      <div class="stp step-2">
        <div class="header">
          <h1 class="title">Select your plan</h1>
          <p class="exp">You have the option of monthly or yearly billing.</p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="plan-card selected">
            <img src="./assets/images/icon-arcade.svg" alt="arcade">
            <div class="plan-info chosen">
              <b>Arcade</b>
              <span class="plan-priced">$9/mo</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="plan-card">
            <img src="./assets/images/icon-advanced.svg" alt="advanced">
            <div class="plan-info">
              <b>Advanced</b>
              <span class="plan-priced">$12/mo</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="plan-card">
            <img src="./assets/images/icon-pro.svg" alt="pro">
            <div class="plan-info">
              <b>Pro</b>
              <span class="plan-priced">$15/mo</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="switcher">
          <p class="monthly sw-active">Monthly</p>
          <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
          <p class="yearly">Yearly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="prev-stp" type="button">Go Back</button>
          <button class="next-stp" type="submit">Next Step</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Step 2 end -->
      <!-- Step 3 start -->
      <div class="stp step-3">
        <div class="header">
          <h1 class="title">Pick add-ons</h1>
          <p class="exp">Add-ons help enhance your gaming experience.</p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <div class="box" data-id="1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="online">
            <div class="description">
              <label for="online">Online service</label>
              <small>Access to multiplayer games</small>
            </div>
            <p class="price">+$1/mo</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" data-id="2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="larger">
            <div class="description">
              <label for="larger">Larger storage</label>
              <small>Extra 1TB of cloud save</small>
            </div>
            <p class="price">+$2/mo</p>
          </div>
          <div class="box" data-id="3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="profile">
            <div class="description">
              <label for="profile">Customizable Profile</label>
              <small>Custom theme on your profile</small>
            </div>
            <p class="price">+$2/mo</p>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="prev-stp" type="button">Go Back</button>
          <button class="next-stp" type="submit">Next Step</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Step 3 end -->
      <!-- Step 4 start -->
      <div class="stp step-4">
        <div class="header">
          <h1 class="title">Finishing up</h1>
          <p class="exp">Double-check everything looks OK before confirming.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="selection-box">
          <div class="selection-container">
            <div class="selected-plan">
              <p class="plan-name">Arcade (Monthly)</p>
              <p class="plan-price">$9/mo</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="addons">
              <div>
                <div class="selected-addon">
                  <span class="service-name">Online Service</span>
                  <span class="service-price">+$1/mo</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class="total">Total (per month) <b>+$12/mo</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
          <button class="prev-stp" type="button">Go Back</button>
          <button class="next-stp" type="submit">Next Step</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Step 4 end -->
      <!-- Step 5 start -->
      <div class="stp step-5">
        <img src="./assets/images/icon-thank-you.svg" alt="thank">
        <div class="header">
          <h1 class="title">Thank You!</h1>
          <p class="exp">
            Thanks for confirming your subscription! We hope you have fun using our platform. If you ever need support, please feel free to email us at support@loremgaming.com.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- Step 5 end -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need `if (nextBtn)` around `nextBtn.addEventListener`. Didn't you see the error in the console?

Comment: The code is stopping when it gets that error, so none of the other event listeners are added.